# RailsがProduction環境で起動できない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby 2.6.0
Rails 5.2.2

production環境で起動したかったため、rails s =e=production を行いhttps://localhost；3000でアクセスしても、無効な応答が返されViewが反映されません。

```
2019-02-09 21:29:59 +0900: HTTP parse error, malformed request (): #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.>
```

このようなエラーが出ます。

Comment: 質問本文では`localhost;3000`と、ホスト名とポート番号の間が「セミコロン」になっていますが、通常であれば「コロン」を入力するはずです。単なる質問の記述ミスか、実際のアクセス時はどうだったかも念のため確認してみてください。

Answer (score 2):

Railsがhttpのリクエストを期待してlistenしているポートにhttpsのTLSアクセスをしようとしているためリクエストを処理できていないようです。`http://localhost:3000`でアクセスしてください
（または意図的にhttpsを使いたいのならなんらかの方法でhttpsでlistenするなりする必要があります）